# Need help finding a specific Magento Javascript file

Tags: magento

I'm hoping that someone in this forum can help with finding a specific JavaScript file in a Magento shopping cart.

I'm working on fixing SSL non secure items messages and I've found and fixed all of them except for one.

The image I'm looking for is called "pager_arrow_right.gif" and it's on a customer account page generated from:

```
app\design\frontend\default\our_theme\template\sales\order\history.phtml
```

The image src code is not in this file though, it looks like the image src is in a JavaScript file generated from that history.phtml file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('my-orders-table')</script>
```

Does anyone have any idea where the JavaScript file for the above code is located?

I just can't seem to find it..

Thank You !!
Janet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `decorateTable` is in `js/varien/js.js` but it only applies some class names. Normally that image is used in pagers for collections. The line following your javascript is:

```
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>
```

...which seems more relevant. Look at the file `template/page/html/pager.phtml` instead.

Comment: Hello clockworkgeek, your answer helped a ton! You were totally right about the gif being in template/page/html/pager.phtml. Finally all of the SSL non secure items have been fixed in the Magento cart. Thank you so much for your help! Janet